# How to pass a defined text into PySpark SQL context

Tags: sql, pyspark

I am pretty new to PySpark and I wonder if there is something like below:

My PySpark SQL context is something like:

```
mysql = """
create table x as
select * 
from a
"""
```

Since I need to change x a lot, and don't want to change it in sql itself every time, I'd like to define something in advance. Like

```
x = 'x'
mysql = """
create table x as
select * 
from a
"""
```

Is there anything similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string substitution?

```py
x = 'x'

mysql = f"""
create table {x} as
select * 
from a
```